# What tool to use for text file that is tab-delimited where string fields are surrounded by quotes?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, text-files, google-cloud-dataprep

As the title suggests, I've run into numerous dead ends when trying to find the correct tool to query my text file. Initially, I tried to import the data into Big Query but ran into an assortment of errors. I then transformed the data into a .csv file via GCP's Dataprep service, then imported that version into Big Query which led to another set of errors. I've tried removing the double quotes from the data using tr command in terminal and rerunning the dataprep/bigquery jobs to no avail. I've run out of options and I'm losing my mind. Please help.

Example of the data listed below:

> "002086182-02"    ""  "ZUPLANTI"  "GARY"  ""  ""  "F" 02/15/1965  04/11/1989  "A" 04/01/1996  "D" "291"   ""  "MCMASTER
> ST"   ""  "PENN
> HILLS"    "PA"    "15222" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  11/03/2020  "2260001"   "2260001-1" 05/08/2021  "117684001" "2260001"   ""  "SC37"  "MN226" "MD305" "STH035"    "STS45""USC18"  "CPC00" "CAC09"

Comment: try replacing all `""` with a tab and import that instead

Answer (score 2):

The text you have posted is separated by `spaces`, not by `tabs`.

If your text is separated by `spaces`, use the following command:

`cat file.csv | tr -s ' ' ',' |tr  -d '"' > new_file.csv`

**Or**, if your file is separated by `tabs`, use the following:

`cat file.csv | tr -s '\t' ',' |tr  -d '"' > new_file.csv`

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I converted my .txt file using the two commands that you provided. I attempted to create a table in BQ with the configurations you provided.  When assuming text was separated by spaces, I received this error: "Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Too many values in row starting at position: 182355317. Found 12 column(s) while expected 11." Assuming tab delimiter, the resulting table only had one field and looked like this:  020006438-02,,BRUCE,DANIEL,JOE,,M,04/27/1973,04/22/2003,A,01/25/2007,R,1130,,STATE AVE,3,,CORAOPOLIS,PA,15108,,,,,,

Comment: Should I convert the txt file to .csv with dataprep first, then apply the commands you provided to the file locally and then reupload to BQ?

Comment: Hi! so, the commands I've provided already convert the file to csv. Changinf the file extension is not important. The error you are showing indicates that some data has more columns than the table expect. Please, show me the table schema (columns names and types) and one example of the data file after you run the commands. Also check the line 182355317, probably there is an error on this data line. Waiting for your feedback to help you.